# Why can't my Meteor app recognize my function?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor app with a `<button>`. The button has an `onclick` event on it that calls a function `verifypwd()`. My function is declared in a file named verifypwd.js which is in the main directory of the app. When I click my button, it tells me it can't find the function. What's wrong?

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <title>KinnockPass</title>
  <script src="verifypwd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="PPRO">
  <div class="vertibox">
    <div id="authorization-box">
      <div id="authorization">
         <h1>Are you a Riley?</h1>
         <input id="password" type="password"/>
         <button id="password-submit" onclick="verifypwd();">Yes, I Am.</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>

 <template name="passed">
 </template>
```

**Main JS File**

```
//Define Route of PPRO Template
Router.route('/', {template: 'PPRO'});
Router.route('/passed');

pwd = new Mongo.Collection("pwd");
```

**verifypwd.js**

```
var verifypwd = function(){
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor wraps all functions so that their scope is restricted to the file they are in unless they are defined as global functions. If you remove `var` from `var verifypwd` it should work. A more meteoric way of doing what you're trying to do is to define a [template event](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events) for your PPRO template and put your *verifypwd* code in the same file, then it can be a local function.

Comment: All of this is correct. I'd add that the literal answer to his question is that the file isn't loading because it isn't being served from `/public`.

Comment: True, one can put function definitions in public as well. Of course that would lead to the question of why are you verifying a password on the client which I should have asked earlier.