# Meteor method not accessing method outside of its file

Tags: meteor

My Meteor methods call generic/utility type of methods that I don't want to keep redefining in each collection file. As long as the method remains inside of the collection file, the method is accessible. Once the method is moved to a different file, this error is generated: `ReferenceError: myMethod is not defined`

The collection file is located in: `lib/collections/posts.js`
If `myMethod()` is located in this `posts.js` file, it is accessible. If I create another file such as `lib/_utils.js` and move `myMethod()` there, it won't load. I intentionally added the underscore for it to load prior to the collection files.

The post titled [Ordering of the css and js files loaded by Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109176/ordering-of-the-css-and-js-files-loaded-by-meteor) explains the order in which the files are loaded, but something is still amiss. I'm guessing this is a security issue surrounding how Meteor methods work.

Can a Meteor method make a call to a method in another .js file? If so, where should this other .js file be located?

This question is answered in post [Why can't my Meteor app recognize my function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929044/why-cant-my-meteor-app-recognize-my-function/31929174#31929174)

Comment: http://vstark.net/2014/09/25/4-things-with-meteor/ also explains the order that Meteor loads the files. My file appears to be in line with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509125/global-variables-in-meteor)

Comment: Also definitely a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929044/why-cant-my-meteor-app-recognize-my-function/31929174#31929174

Comment: @MichelFloyd Maybe not, we would need to see some MCVE to be sure.

Comment: True but function scope is such a common beginner problem.

Comment: Thanks, @MichelFloyd. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929044/why-cant-my-meteor-app-recognize-my-function/31929174#31929174  answers my question. This isn't a question about global variables, but how Meteor works. As you stated: "Meteor wraps all functions so that their scope is restricted to the file they are in unless they are defined as global functions."

Comment: It's one of those things that you run to in the first 24h with Meteor. There will be more ;)